# Do i need to call Platform.runLater for updating UI if i'm working on JavaFX Application Thread

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, javafx-2, java.util.concurrent

Do i need to create a new `Runnable` object and run `Platform.runLater` if i'm still working on JavaFX Application Thread for updating UI. For example, i need to update a Text object which is imported in Controller Class from a fxml file, and i will call a static method from another class to do this. Moreover, the imported Text object is static, so is it safe to call static object like;

```
ControllerClass.textLabel.setText("foobar");
```

or even if i'm working on JavaFX Application Thread, should using Platform.runLater will be more safe for updating UI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You do not need to use `Platform.runLater` if you are already in the JavaFX application thread.